# SimpleXML Export "SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(" in Variable

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm trying to take a variable from an xml file and save it as a php file

```
     $xmlresponse = simplexml_load_string($dom->saveXML());
   $shipmentid = $xmlresponse->ListInboundShipmentsResult->ShipmentData->member->ShipmentId;
 echo '<br />' . $shipmentid . '<br />';


 $todaydt = new DateTime('today');
 $today3 = $todaydt->format('m-d-Y') . PHP_EOL;
 $today = rtrim($today3);
$var_str = var_export($shipmentid, true);
$var = "<?php\n\n\$shipmentid = $var_str;\n\n?>";
file_put_contents('shipmentid_' . $today . '.php', $var);

 }
```

But in my `shipmentid_11-11-2016.php` file it is giving me

> $shipmentid = SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
>      0 => 'shipmentid',
>      ));

How can I save the variable so it is just simply

> $shipmentid = 'shipmentid';

?

Comment: `$var_str = strval($shipmentid);`

Comment: Thank you! Looks like it is converting it to an integer though... `$shipmentid = FBA000AAA;`  Needs to be `$shipmentid = 'FBA000AAA';`. hmm..

Comment: Added the quotes on this line `$var = "<?php\n\n\$shipmentid = '$var_str';\n\n?>";` and it works.  Thanks again!  Feel free to post as an answer so I can mark resolved..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
echo '<br />' . $shipmentid . '<br />';
```

php implicitly converts `$shipmentid` value to a string. `var_export` does not do it, so you need to convert it by yourself:

```
$var_str = strval($shipmentid);
```

Next thing is that `$var_str` is a string and does not contains any quotes around. So, again you need to write quotes by yourself:

```
// with double quotes
$var = "<?php\n\n\$shipmentid = \"$var_str\";\n\n?>";
// with single quotes
$var = "<?php\n\n\$shipmentid = '$var_str';\n\n?>";
```